# How to read a text file and write it with a new line whenever a comma is encountered?

Tags: python, string, file, io, formatting

I simply want to know a small script or built-in function that can read a text corpus and write it with a new line whenever a comma was encountered during parsing.

```
hello,world,rick,and,morty should be
hello,
world,
rick,
and,
morty
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the implementation of your read write process, but you can easily replace commas with comma+newline:

```
line = line.replace(',',',\n')
```

The reading bit could be something like:

```
with open('filetoread.txt', r) as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    line = line.replace(',',',\n')
    # ...now write these to a file or print the lines, etc.
```

Comment: would regex be more efficient?

Comment: not in this case. replace() is fast and re.sub() is about the same, but less simple for such a clear-cut case like this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the job it by :

```
f = open('filename', 'r+')
n = f.read().replace(',', ',\n') # do the job!
f.truncate(0)                    # remove file contents from begin
f.write(n)                       # write result into file :)
f.close()
```